$\mathbb{N}$ is uncountable?
I recently saw a proof that $\mathbb{R}$ is uncountable using Baire's Category Theorem.
It goes like this:
Suppose $\mathbb{R}$ is countable then $\mathbb{R} = \cup(x_n)$. Since $\mathbb{R}$ is complete $\cup(x_n)$ is of second category in $\mathbb{R}$. However each $\{x_n\}$ is nowhere dense in $\mathbb{R}$. Thus $\cup(x_n)$ is of first category in $\mathbb{R}$, a contradiction.
Now let's apply the same process to $\mathbb{N}$:
Suppose $\mathbb{N}$ is countable then $\mathbb{N} = \cup(x_n)$. Since $\mathbb{N}$ is complete $\cup(x_n)$ is of second category in $\mathbb{N}$. However each $\{x_n\}$ is nowhere dense in $\mathbb{N}$. Thus $\cup(x_n)$ is of first category in $\mathbb{N}$, a contradiction.
The only flaw I could foresee in this proof is that $\{x_n\}$ is not nowhere dense in $\mathbb{N}$, however I can't seem to prove this fact. Could someone please point out my mistake for me?

A set is nowhere dense if the interior of its closure is the empty set. Under the discrete metric, the closure of $\{x_n\}$ is just $\{x_n\}$. Further, $x_n$ is also an interior point of $\{x_n\}$, thus $\{x_n\}$ is not nowhere dense, under the discrete topology.
